# Use multichannel noise spatially diffused for multichannel diarization

Tags: impulse-response, audio-processing, speech, multi-channel

I'm trying to implement speaker diarization (who speaks when) for mono recording audio (1 channel), but now I'm starting to work with multichannel audio (stereo - 2 channels), so I need for data augmentation to use multichannel spatially diffuse noise, I'm new to this.

Do I have to use impulse response, maybe multichannel impulse response, reverberation? Those are terms that I heard but don't know exactly if they are useful for my problem.

NB: The noise that I used for mono-channel diarization is from torch-audiomentations => AddBackgroundNoise.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use Binaural Room Impulse Responses (BRIR) from each speaker to each ear for a variety of speaker locations, listener head orientations and different room reverberation times. The BRIR will encode the spatial cues as well as room reverberation. Here is a shitty drawing of what the BRIR is.
[image]

The two sources are $S_1$ and $S_2$ and their path to the left and right ear are represented by the filters $h_{i,L}$ and $h_{i,R}$. In an anechoic case (no reverberation), direct paths from the sources to the ears would be adequate (shown in black). However, in a room you will also have wall reflections contributing to the BRIR (shown in blue). There are many such reflections bouncing off the multiple walls and there will be many peaks in your BRIRs (shown in red). Note that source 1 reaches the left ear earlier than the right ear. The difference in amplitude of the first peak in the left and right channel is the interaural level difference and the time delay between the first peak in the two channels is the interaural level difference and these are the most important cues for localisation. You can see that as the listener rotates their head or the source moves, these cues will change.

So if you convolve your mono speech with the BRIR, you will get a stereo signal that encodes the spatial and the room cues. Typical BRIR datasets will have 2 channel outputs for a large number of speaker positions and head orientations, for multiple rooms. Here is one https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/ebrird/. Note that having the spatial cues will actually make diarization much easier unless both the sources are at the same location (or very closeby).

Comment: But if I have multichannel database done with microphone arrays, is I still need to use the BRIR, because in your response, you said I need to convolve my mono speech with BRIB, to get the stereo signal, but I already have .wav files that represent microphone arrays, and each contains 8 channels, And I'm willing to pick the very first 2 channels from each array and add to them spatially diffused noise . Am I doing this right ?

Comment: and knowing that I made the 8 channels database by writing a .wav file with 8 .wav files from AMI Dataset of this link https://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/ami/AMICorpusMirror/amicorpus/   , if you open the link you will see that each conversation file have 2 arrays audios files and each array have 8 audio wav files recorded by the same conversation , but with different positions of speakers, so I combined those 8 .wav files into 1 file to build a 8-channels dataset .

Comment: And I want to add a multichannel noise to my multichannel dataset, so Is this a right thing to do? or do I need to use the BRIR with mono-channel dataset as you said

Comment: I want to ask you if I convolve the BRIR to my first mono dataset, do I will get as output a stereo signal with spatial cues such as revebration, and what about noise, How can I add it?

Comment: I mean how I can add spatial cues of the noise's source compared to the 2 micros?

Comment: What I want to do is to convolve my mono noise that comes from audiomentations with the BRIRs, to get stereo noise ?

Comment: Do you have access to Acoustic Transfer Functions or covariance matrix for these microphone arrays?